# How to dynamically create a generic list based on a type determined at runtime

Tags: c#, system.reflection

How can I change the class type in the list based on a condition like  this:

```
var clsBoName;
if(Type==1)
{
    clsBoName=clsBOManageRoles;
}
else 
{
    clsBoName=clsBOManageOthers;
}

List<clsBoName> RoleCapabilityList = new List<clsBoName>();
```

clsBOManageRoles, clsBOManageOthers are classes

please suggest me

Comment: Create an interface and let both classes inherit that interface then a method with parameter of type of that interface.

Comment: Are clsBOManageRoles and clsBOManageOthers related in any way? How do you go on to use RoleCapabilityList?

Comment: @Hammerstein No clsBOManageRoles and clsBOManageOthers not related any way

Comment: So, how do you go on to use RoleCapabilityList, or do you see yourself checking to see what it contains every time you want to use it?

Comment: @Hammerstein
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver());
List<clsBoName> RoleCapabilityList = new List<clsBoName>();
RoleCapabilityList = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<clsBOManageRoles>>(RoleList);//Deserialize list.

RoleList is json array 

then we convert to xml

Comment: Those are two different lists, you can't just make them fit. Unless they inherit from a base class in some way (as has been suggested), you're going to need to work with two different lists.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to create a base class or an interface that both clsBOManageRoles and clsBOManageOthers derive from.

Comment: we not create object of this class ,I want to change class name in List<>